# Xamarin.iOS xcode error: Error Updating objective C type information

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios

I'm working with Xcode interface builder to create UI for Xamairn.iOS native application. It is working fine but from last 6 days, it's giving the error when I'm trying to open the Main.Storyboard with Xcode. If i create the new project and try to use xcode for ui it works but after one or two time work it also gives this error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution today, I hope this will help someone one or another way!

I have used **Xamarin.iOS.MaterialComponents 39.0.0** for creating **FloatingActionButton** as it's required in my app, but because of this component, I'm not able to modify my Main.Storyboard using Xcode. Today, I have removed that package from my app and it started working with Xcode exactly the way I want it to work.

So, the problem is in the package's new version(i.e., 39.0.0). How I'm that much sure? Because I have used it's 35.2.0 version as I have to use a floating action button and it's working like charm.

I have posted the issue on https://github.com/ilap/MaterialComponentsXamarin/issues/2 hope that it will get resolved soon.