# Visual Studio for Mac 17.6.3 won't open storyboard

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, maui, .net-ios

I have updated macOS to version 13.5.1, Visual Studio to version 17.6.3, and Xcode to version 14.3.1. I have an older Xamarin.iOS project that was created in 2016. While the project can build, and I can use it on the simulator, I am encountering an issue where the storyboard does not open. I receive the following error message: "Error updating Objective-C type information."

Is there anyone who has experience dealing with this issue? Alternatively, is there a way for me to access more detailed error information?

Comment: Can the storyboard be opened if you create a new Xamarin.iOS project with default template?

Comment: Yes it can. I did it with brand new .NET iOS and it took lots of my days. However, it is on the test phase by the team and for our current development progress, i need to use old version.

Comment: Hi, you could  try  creating new storyboards and copy the xml from the previous storyboard to new storyboards. Can it be opened now?

Comment: No, even new and empty storyboard can not be opened. It is about Xamarin.iOS SDK  version I think.

Comment: There are some similar issues which you may refer to : [What does mean "Error updating Objective-C type information"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/251165/what-does-mean-error-updating-objective-c-type-inf) , [Xamarin.iOS xcode error: Error Updating objective C type information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366226/xamarin-ios-xcode-error-error-updating-objective-c-type-information), [Visual Studio Could not Communicate with XCode](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-could-not-communicate-with-xcode-1/1096590)

Comment: And do you use any third party nuget package?  Maybe you could update them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to migrate your old Xamarin.iOS project to .NET iOS. During the migration, if you have numerous dependencies such as NuGet packages, you must handle all of them. Additionally, remember that many of the packages have been deprecated and has no support. You should obtain the source code, build them with your .NET iOS project's .NET version, and use the NuGet packages as DLLs.